# Android Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method showToast(String) from the type LoginActivity

Tags: android, static

I am pretty new to android app development and java and I encountered the following error when trying to call a method from another class:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method showToast(String) from the type LoginActivity
```

The reason I want to call this in the other class and not instantiate it in the class itself is because of adaptability and upgradeability issues. This seems a fine concept by me or is it something that is way overrated?

The relevant code is:

CreateAccountActivity

```
public class NewAccountActivity extends Activity{

private Button mCreateAccountButton;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.newaccount);

    mCreateAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createaccount_button);

    registerButtonListeners();

    }

    private void registerButtonListeners() {
        mCreateAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LoginActivity.showToast(getString(R.string.createaccount_message));
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

LoginActivity

```
public void showToast(String toastString) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

    ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastImage);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastText);
    text.setText(toastString);

    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show(); 
}
```

Creating a new LoginActivity object and then calling showToast on it makes the error messages go away but gives me a NullPointerException instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to call showToast in the static way you have to make the method showToast static.

```
public static void showToast(...)
```

Edit: where do you get the NullPointerException?

Comment: making showToast static doesn't work since getLayoutInflater gives the same "cannot make a static reference ..." error.
The Nullpointer exception is with the getLayoutInflater

Comment: Could you try LayoutInflater inflater =LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()); instead of getLayoutInflater(); ?

Comment: did that and replaced the findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root) by a variable that is instantiated during the oncreate method and passed to showToast and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should not create Objects from Activity on you own. Activities should be instantiated through the system, they go through a fairly complex lifecycle that is managed by the OS itself and won't work if they are not following the lifecycle correct.

There are two possibilities to create maintainable code that actually runs for your problem:

1. Create a static helper function somewhere in another class and pass in an activity object that you use to get a layout inflater and actually show the Toast. This way every activity can use the showToast method without dependencies between your activities.
2. Create a base activity that is extended by all your activities that has a public method showToast. This way you do not need to pass in a context method and every one of your activities just has the ability to show a Toast. This has some problems if you are extending different Activities like FragmentActivity, ListActivity, TabActivity.

I would go with the first method and create something like a Util or ToastUtil class that holds the Toast functionality at one place for all your activities.